Which is better using CTE's or Joining all tables
I have a query that has a lot of left joins and I only retrieved one column for most of the left joins is it better to just use CTE for each table to only retrieve what is needed or is it better
or is it better to just continue joining all those tables even if I only need one for each left join.

The answer depends on a) your actual SQL code, which you haven't shared, and also b) your actual SQL database.  You've tagged for both Oracle and Postgres, but it turns out, these two databases implement CTEs very differently.  Please include these details.

Run your horses.

It doesn't matter how many columns you want from a table. For the DBMS
select t1.a, t2.b 
from t1
left join t2 using (x)

is the same as
select dt1.a, dt2.b 
from (select x, a from t1) dt1
left join (select x, b from t2) dt2 using (x)

or
with dt1 as (select x, a from t1) 
     dt2 as (select x, b from t2)
select dt1.a, dt2.b 
from dt1
left join dt2 using (x)

So, keep it simple. Just join the tables. This makes the query easy to read and thus easy to maintain.
Once you aggregate data, however, you will usually want to aggregate before joining:
with upv as (select post_id, count(*) as total from upvotes group by post_id) 
     dnv as (select post_id, count(*) as total from downvotes group by post_id)
select
  post_id,
  coalesce(upv.total, 0) as total_upvotes,
  coalesce(dnv.total, 0) as total_downvotes
from upv
full outer join dnv using (x)
order by post_id;


It can make a difference when you use the CTE tables more than once, because Oracle can store the result in a temporary table (you can enforce this with undocumented hint /*+ MATERIALIZE */) and gain performance by re-use it in the main query.

Same thing in PostgreSQL. From the manual: A WITH query that is referenced more than once in FROM is computed only once, unless specified otherwise with NOT MATERIALIZED.
